# How can I have global error handling in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, typescript, error-handling, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I search a lot but I didn't found any source about that, In the most place, I do DB action that  I have to use `try/catch` and this is annoying, That's why I want to get rid of `try/catch` while using `Sequelize`.

```
try {
    await this.db.Student.create({ name: 'xxx', family: 'xxx' })
}
catch {
    // handle error 
}
```

**Is it possible to have global error handling?**

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of try/catch? What is the goal? How do you want to use global error handling - just swallow the errors? Log?